# How to repair a corrupted .mts video?

Tags: video, software-recommendation

I've got hold of some .mts video files from work, the source is unknown so there is no hardware recovery option. Unfortunately I'm left with these files and they seem to be corrupted, how do I fix it?

Comment: Which players have you tried?

Comment: VLC, flash I even tried importing it into Final Cut Pro everything failed.